# How do you manage module instances in conjunction with background processes?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I'm working on a Titanium mobile app, I'm using [this geofencing module](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ci.geofencing), and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to register a background service that can continue to receive geofence callbacks when the app is paused.

The problem I'm having is this:

If I try registering the geofence in a background service, I end up having two running instances of the module, both of which run geofence enter/exit callbacks (this happens each time I pause and resume the app, resulting in another region monitoring each time the app is either paused or resumed). If I *don't* register the geofence in the bg service, no callbacks run.

I tried referencing a global version of the module using something like:

`ci_geofencing = Alloy.Globals.ci_geofencing`

But it appears that the Alloy object isn't available to the background service.

Any suggestions for how this can be handled gracefully?

Comment: I have your exact same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I wasn't understanding the issue:

In ios, region monitoring doesn't require a background process. When a fence is triggered, the app is woken up to run the specified callback. So you don't actually have to do any background process setup to work with a geofence.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to manage instances of modules in Titanium, but regarding the background process/geofence issue, it's not something you have to worry about.